# Relational Query in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have 4 classes in Parse. I am using JavaScript.

```
1)  Rangoli - Main item objects
2) Categories - List of all categories
3) Users - List of all users
4) ItemCategories - List of categories that each items are assigned
```

Below is the structure of all classes.

[image]

Now I am trying to get the following details in a single query.

```
1) User - Name, email, avatar
2) Rangoli - filename, createdAt
3) Categories - name
```

This is the JavaScript code that I tried.

```
var Rangoli = Parse.Object.extend("Rangoli");
var ItemCategories = Parse.Object.extend("ItemCategories");

var query = new Parse.Query(ItemCategories);

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Rangoli);

innerQuery.matchesQuery("category", query);

query.find({
    success : function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error : function (e) {
    }
});
```

With the above JavaScript code, I am getting the record of ItemCategories record and not all the columns of all pointer class like Categories, User, Rangoli.

Comment: Why not to add  Category column in the Rangoli class. 
The column type should be "pointer to Category" if the relation is 1:1. if the relation is 1:0..100, the type should be "array of Category." so, CategoryItem class is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include related objects in the results of a query by using the [include](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#include) method.  e.g.

```
var ItemCategories = Parse.Object.extend("ItemCategories");
var query = new Parse.Query(ItemCategories);
query.include("item");
query.include("category");
```

You can also use this to get objects nested at multiple levels, e.g., `query.include(["category.rangoli"]);` but from your data model screenshot I can't see a way to include the Rangoli data with the relationships you have set up.

Comment: If you have suggestions to change the data model, please let me know.