# Data model design for Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have currently having 4 classes in Parse.

```
1)  Rangoli - Main item objects
2) Categories - List of all categories
3) Users - List of all users
4) ItemCategories - List of categories that each items are assigned
```

Below is the structure of all classes. I am facing difficulties in queries when the item has multiple categories. I am getting duplicates.

Whats the best way of designing this data model which will allow us to query by category and get all columns.

[image]

For detailed issue on the query, please refer to [Relational Query in Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186454/relational-query-in-parse/29187549#29187549)

Comment: You could do a join? These classes are relational tables after all

Comment: We could not do traditional SQL on parse cloud. I am having problems with joins provided by Parse. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186454/relational-query-in-parse/29187549#29187549

Comment: You could make category a Relation or Array

Comment: Thanks @Simba. Bu can you please explain in which class, i should make it?

Comment: Wait, just- re-read the question could you clarify what you are trying to query?

Comment: @Simba: sure I can explain. I like to get all Rangoli, User and multiple category details in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make category a Relation or Array.

See:

[documentation](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetomany)

You could make category in item categories a relation, or you could add a categories column in Rangoli and scrap the ItemCategories table.

edit-
You could make Categories a column in Rangoli. Now when you query for items, you also get all their categories, You could still use your other table to get all the items in a category, and that mapping a lot easier. Now you get both use cases

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. Still trying to understand the action items. should the categories column in Rangoli be a Relationship type?

Comment: So the only difference from your current scheme is that Rangoli would have a new column :"Categories". If a Rangoli will have a small amount of categories (10 or less) on an average use case make it an array. Otherwise make it a Relation

Comment: It will be 1 or 2 or maximum 3. When its defined as array, won't it be difficult to query them directly? I guess we need to parse the array manually to query the itesm of particular type in array. please correct me if wrong.

Comment: If you need to query by category you use your itemcategory table, if you need to query by item and get the categories you have to do that extra step to get the data out of the array unfortunately. It would be nice if Parse added a "unique" constraint, which would allow you to have just used the itemcategory table.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will try now and ask you if I have any questions.